# f distribution with fitdistr

Tags: r, distribution

RStudio Version 0.98.1049

MASS version 7.3-33

```
x <- rf(1000, 31, 9)
fitdistr(x, 'f', start=list(31, 9))

Error in as.function.default(c(value, if (is.null(bd) || is.list(bd)) list(bd) else bd),  : 
use of NULL environment is defunct
```

The error is too cryptic for me to understand. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: The RStudio version is almost never relevant here. The R version might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` parameter expects a named list:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rf(1000, 31, 9)

library(MASS)
fitdistr(x, 'f', start=list(31, 9))
#Error in densfun(x, parm, ...) : 
#  argument "df2" is missing, with no default

fitdistr(x, 'f', start=list(df1=31, df2=9))
#     df1          df2    
# 22.1259170   10.6960522 
#( 3.3765675) ( 0.8678625)
```

Study the documentation.

Comment: Also make sure you do not have a global `df` variable... I got bitten by this.